# Exporting Data file in .dat format

Tags: export, dataset

Here I'm solving two simultaneous to get different values  of the roots depending upon another variable 'x'. I've written up to the following using  'Find Root'

```
g[x_] = 2*x; 
f1[p_, q_] = 2*g[x]*p^4 + q^2;
f2[p_, q_] = 5 p^2 + q - g[x]; 
For[x = 0, x < 10, x = x + 1, 
  Print[{p, q, x} /.
    FindRoot[{f1[p, q] - 5 == 0, f2[p, q] - 10 == 0}, {{p, 5}, {q, 1}}]]];
```

Now can I export this in a data file (three column)?

Comment: Have you looked at `Export`?

Comment: Trying to figure out how to use that here.

Comment: It's kind of hard to comment on this without working code.  (e.g. define f1, f2, fix the {{p,1},{p,2}} etc.)

Comment: Something like this 'g[x_] = 2*x;
f1[p_, q_] = 2*g[x]*p^4 + q^2;
f2[p_, q_] = 5 p^2 + q - g[x];
For[x = 0, x < 10, x = x + 1, 
  Print[FindRoot[{f1[p, q] - 5 == 0, 
     f2[p, q] - 10 == 0}, {{p, 5}, {q, 1}}]]];'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Table`, not `For`:

```
output = Table[
    {p, q, x} /. FindRoot[{f1[p, q] - 0.03 == 0, f2[p, q] - 0.0234 == 0}, {{p, 1}, {q, 2}}],
    {x, 0, 359}
  ]
```

Look in `$ExportFormats` to find the format you want.

```
Export["output.csv", output]
```

Comment: I've fixed the {{p,1},{p,2}} thing.  I think it's very odd that your code doesn't use x anywhere.

Comment: Can one use 'Export' when we are using 'For'?

Comment: Don't use For. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18396#18396